# Undefined Variable on fetching data in view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to print values in from database in table. However the error shows undefined variable outlets in app.blade.php. I'm a beginner in laravel I've copied the function from index.blade.php where it is working. Any help will be highly appreciative.

App.blade.php:

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <form method="GET" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-inline">
                                <input type="submit" value="{{ __('outlet.search') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                <a href="{{ route('outlets.index') }}" class="btn btn-link">{{ __('app.reset') }}</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-sm table-responsive-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">{{ __('app.table_no') }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __('outlet.name') }}</th>
                                    
                                    <th class="text-center">{{ __('app.action') }}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($outlets as $key => $outlet)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ $outlets->firstItem() + $key }}</td>
                                <td>{!! $outlet->name_link !!}</td>
                                <td>{{ $outlet->address }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $outlet->latitude }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $outlet->longitude }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="{{ route('outlets.show', $outlet) }}" id="show-outlet-{{ $outlet->id }}">{{ __('app.show') }}</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                         </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="card-body">{{ $outlets->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() }}</div>
```

OutletController.php

```
  public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('manage_outlet');

        $outletQuery = Outlet::query();
        $outletQuery->where('name', 'like', '%'.request('q').'%');
        $outlets = $outletQuery->paginate(25);

        return view('outlets.index', compact('outlets'));
    }

    public function app()
    {
        
        
        $outlets = "this is outlet";

        return view('outlets.app', compact('outlets'));
    }
```

Error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
> Undefined variable: outlets (View: /home/converse/laravel_leaflet_1/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /home/converse/laravel_leaflet_1/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Comment: If you use dd('test') in public function app() did you see it ?

Comment: hi thanks for replying could you elaborate a little more. thanks

Comment: What are you doing exactly, in view you are doing this `$outlets->firstItem()`, `$outlets` is an array, how `firstItem()` will work on it.